# Join with group by Doctrine Symfony

Tags: symfony3, doctrine

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->leftJoin('a.arrivalProducts', 'p')
        ->select('a', 'SUM(p.cost*p.qty) as sum')
        ->groupBy('a.id')
        ->addGroupBy('p.currencyId')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

результат 2 строки. Если `getArrayResult`, то три строки. Прямой запрос выдает три строки:

```
SELECT a0_.id AS id_0, a0_.user_id AS user_id_1, a0_.warehouse_id AS warehouse_id_2, 
       a0_.created_at AS created_at_3, a0_.updated_at AS updated_at_4,
       SUM(a1_.cost * a1_.qty) AS sclr_5, a0_.user_id AS user_id_6,
       a0_.warehouse_id AS warehouse_id_7 
           FROM arrival a0_ LEFT JOIN arrival_product a1_ ON a0_.id = a1_.arrival_id 
   GROUP BY a0_.id, a1_.currency_id;
```

Это прямой запрос. Почему объектов два, а в массиве три, как и должно быть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dump() с помощью которой выводятся данные иногда балуется и показывает разные результаты.